# can not call method from the main class?

Tags: java, variables

i am trying to make a web browser and here is my code

CODE:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.applet.*;

public class browserPannel extends JFrame{

    public static void main(String[] arg)
    {
        JFrame browser = new JFrame("A Nun In A Weelchair");
        browser.setSize(1000,700);
        browser.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        browser.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        browser.pack();
        browser.setVisible(true);

        JPanel header = new JPanel();
        header.setBackground(Color.lightGray);
        header.setVisible(true);

        final JEditorPane htmlc = new JEditorPane();
        htmlc.setBackground(Color.red);
        htmlc.setEditable(true);
        htmlc.setContentType("text/html");
        htmlc.setVisible(true);

        final JTextField url = new JTextField(20);

        url.setSize(890,30);
        url.setVisible(true);

        url.addActionListener(
            new ActionListener()
            {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
                {
                    loadHtml(htmlc, url, event.getActionCommand());
                    System.out.println("action performed");
                }
            }
            );

        JButton send = new JButton("Send");
        send.setSize(75,30);
        send.setVisible(true);


        header.add(url, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        header.add(send);
        browser.getContentPane().add(header, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        browser.getContentPane().add(new JScrollPane(htmlc));
    }

    private void loadHtml(JEditorPane htmlc, JTextField url, String link)
    {
        try{
            htmlc.setPage(link);
            url.setText(link);
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("ops sorry could not fined Virgine Mobile");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

and here is my error message:

```
browserPannel.java:38: error: non-static method loadHtml(JEditorPane,JTextField,
String) cannot be referenced from a static context
                                        loadHtml(htmlc, url, event.getActionComm
and());
                                        ^
1 error
```

as you can tell it is getting errors from the loadHtml which is defined in a method at the buttom of my code, now if i remove the loadHtml, then it displays the println("action Performed");, but only when i refer the loadHtml it says that it that the non static method can not be preformed in a static method.

Comment: Did you bother to search for other questions about referencing non-static methods from a static context?  This question has been asked SO MANY times!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct. You need an instance of your class `browserPannel` to invoke that method,

```
browserPannel bp = new browserPannel();
bp.loadHtml(htmlc, url, event.getActionCommand());
```

or you can make

```
private void loadHtml(JEditorPane htmlc, JTextField url, String link)
```

`static`, like

```
private static void loadHtml(JEditorPane htmlc, JTextField url, String link)
```

**Edit**

Also, Java camel case conventions would name your class `BrowserPanel` (and I suggest you follow that convention).

Answer (score 0):

As you have called the "loadHtml" from main method you will have to do either of the below:-

1) use object of `browserPannel` class to call loadHtml or

2) you will need the loadHtml method to be static

remember the rule `static and within the same class can be directly called from main method`

cheers!